# Ansible Run second playbook only if the first one is done correctly

Tags: ansible

I’ll tell you about my scenario. I have a host file with two servers and two playbooks.

I need to perform the following, first I have to run a playbook on server number 1 and if there is no errors, I need to run the second playbook on server number 2.
What condition should I use?

```
 - name: Execute the First Play
   import_playbook: first-playbook-to-run.yml

 - name: Run the Second Playbook
   import_playbook: second-playbook-to-run.yml
```

Any helps?
Regards,

Comment: You could use the [keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) `any_errors_fatal: true` in your first playbook. This will ensure that second play starts only when all tasks of first playbook were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
- name: Execute the First Play
  import_playbook: first-playbook-to-run.yml
  delegate_to: server1
  run_once: true

- name: Run the Second Playbook
  import_playbook: second-playbook-to-run.yml
  delegate_to: server2
  run_once: true
```